# How to setup Sonarcloud with code coverage for a .NET project using Coverlet

Tags: .net, unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarcloud

I'm trying to setup a pipeline that runs sonarscanner, unit tests with code coverage. I can't figure out why it is not working. I'm getting no errors but in sonarcloud is saying 0 errors and 0% coverage.

Coverlet open cover is creating XML file that is actually confirming that there is a percentage covered.

this is my repository: https://github.com/Kwebbel-project/tweet-service/tree/development

This is how my pipeline looks

```
name: Development

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "development" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "development" ]

jobs:
  Analysis:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup dotnet
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          
      - name: Install Sonar global tool
        run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner
        
      - name: Begin sonar scan
        run: | 
          dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"Kwebbel-project_tweet-service" /o:"kwebbel-project"  /d:sonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io /d:sonar.login=${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }} /d:sonar.verbose=true 
        
      - name: Build and run unit tests
        run: |
          dotnet restore
          dotnet build
          dotnet test -p:CollectCoverage=true -p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover -o="coverage.xml"
          
      - name: End Sonar scan
        run: dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login=${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: This wasn't working because each job in a Github workflow runs in a separate virtual environment. In other words, "Begin sonar scan" was started in one environment, your tests ran in the other while the scan was ended in yet another environment and nothing was recorded. In order for this to work you need to combine all 3 jobs into 1 where you begin recording, run tests and end recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I couldn't solve the problem with Sonarcloud so I tried another integration with Codecov. This is how my new Continuous integration pipeline looks.

```
name: Continuous integration

on:
 push:
   branches: [ "development", "master" ]
 pull_request:
   branches: [ "development", "master" ]

jobs:
 Analysis:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest

   steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v3
     - name: Setup dotnet
       uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
       with:
         dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
         
     - name: Restore dependencies
       run: dotnet restore
       
     - name: Run Unit tests and create coverage report
       run: dotnet test tweet-service.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:IncludeTestAssembly=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover /p:ExcludeByFile=\"**/Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.Program.cs\"
         
     - name: Upload coverage reports to Codecov
       uses: codecov/codecov-action@v3
       with:
         token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
         fail_ci_if_error: true
         files: ./coverage.opencover.xml
```